# finding a children of each node of an XmlDataSource asp control

Tags: asp.net, xpath, repeater, xmldatasource

i'm trying to view this rss feed :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss">
  <channel>
    <Group>
      <Team>
        <teamID></teamID>
        <name></name>
      </Team>
      <Team>
        <teamID></teamID>
        <name></name>
      </Team>
    </Group>
    <Group>
     <Team>
        <teamID></teamID>
        <name></name>
      </Team>
      <Team>
        <teamID></teamID>
        <name></name>
      </Team>
    </Group>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

in a multiple tables using  the **xmlDatasource asp control**  and **repeater** control

i can only list all the teams of the document using this :

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" XPath="rss/channel/group/team"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

and binding it to the repeater. or finding the groups only

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" XPath="rss/channel/group/team"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

but i can't figure out how to find the children of the xpath . 
i mean if i used nested repeaters one for the groups and the other for the teams 
how to access the teams info .

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" XPath="rss/channel/group/team"></asp:XmlDataSource>
> ```
>
> but i can't figure out how to find the children of the xpath.

**Use**:

```
rss/channel/group/team/*
```

This selects any element that is a child of anu `team` that is selected by the Xpath expression `rss/channel/group/team`